# TimestampBehavior does not work because of failing validation

Tags: validation, yii2, behavior

I have the following class with a [TimestampBehaviour](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html):

```
/**
 * @property int    $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property int    $created_at
 */
class Workspace extends yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'workspace';
    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            [
                'class'      => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_at',
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => false,
                ],
                'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ],
        ];
    }
    ...
}
```

For some reason the behavior does not populate the property. It is always empty when I try to save the model (`$workspace->save()`). I cannot save it since validation fails ("created_at cannot be blank"). There is nothing special with this class. Nothing is overridden. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the validation rules caused the troubles. Unexpected, since I thought all is correct. These were my rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['id', 'name', 'created_at'], 'required'],
        [['id'], 'int'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['created_at' ], 'datetime'],
    ];
}
```

`created_at` must not be *required* - that was the problem.

It is even [documented](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html):

> Because attribute values will be set automatically by this behavior,
>   they are usually not user input and should therefore not be validated,
>   i.e. created_at and updated_at should not appear in the rules() method
>   of the model.

When [`$workspace->save()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail) gets executed then the first step is the validation. And only after that step the [EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT-detail)/[EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE-detail) gets triggered which causes TimestampBehaviour to populate the specified fields. And this happens only if the validation was successful! (if you var_dump you will indeed see an empty created_at.) Too late, validation has taken place already and I've got the validation error.

Recommended solution is to remove created_at from the *required* rule. Other approaches are also possible, of course (e.g. turn off validation or pass the properties that should be validated when save() gets called).

Answer (score 0):

Add behaviour like bellow

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'create_time',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'update_time',
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

and add it to safe records in your model class.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('create_time,update_time', 'safe'),
    );
}
```